# Update the first screen automatically even if it is declared as android:launchMode="singleTask"

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 2 activities. Activity A and Activity B. Both calling each other though intent. Activity A calls Activity B. Activity B accesses database and sends it back to activity A through putExtra() and getExtra().
Now my activity A is in declared like this **android:launchMode="singleTask"**
When I go back to activity A I want my this activity A to be updated or refreshed automatically. But to my wonder what I understood on debugging that if I declare an activity as launchMode="singleTask" then it just brings forth the screen to top from the stack. It does not actually go inside the code.
Is the concept what I understood correct ?
The solution I see is have a refresh button and on click of that access the code and update screen. But I do not want to do that. Do you think there is any other alternative ? I do not want to change launchMode="singleTask"

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried startActivityForResult(intent); and while coming back to A check the result and update your A.

Comment: well I have not tried it yet but I doubt if it will help because as I said code is not being accessed at all. But yes you may be right too, I am going to give it a try.

Comment: hey It works, thank you so much. Please post your answer as a different column, so that I can vote for it. Thanks

Comment: Oh pleased to know. I'll surely post the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `startActivityForResult(intent);` and while you have finished in B `setResult(RESULT_OK);` and `finish();` the B activity, and in A `onActivityResult(int,int,intent);` catch the result code if it is RESULT_OK update your A.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which launchMode, when you switch from Activity B to Activity A, the onResume() method must be invoked. You can put your refresh code there to get your activity A updated.

Comment: I am not doing any onPause() so how do I do onResume() ? Can you please explain with any example. Thanks.

Comment: Read the LifeCycle of Activity: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle , whenever your Activity A is bring to background (i.e. Not in front), it will go to onPause state.

Answer (score 0):

put your refresh part in the onResume method .Once Activity B completed your onResume method will be invoked in Activity A.